# Variable value passed in present view controller is not persistent

Tags: swift, variables, delegates

I'm changing a variable value in a `UIViewController` i will present this way:

```
let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "downloadcontroller") as! DownloadViewController
vc.isFromChangeLangauge = true    //here
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

The new `DownloadViewController` is presented and when i print the `isFromChangeLanguage` variable from `viewDidLoad` in the console is it changed to `true` and all is fine. But when i try to use it in any of the `DownloadViewController` extensions which i use delegate functions in them like `URLSessionDelegate`, `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` the variable is back to its default value which is `false`

```
extension DownloadViewController: URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

        print("Download finished")
        print("IS FROM CHANGE LAGNAUGE 2: \(self.isFromChangeLangauge)") // HERE
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to do here is i just want to know if this download view controller presented from the language setting view controller or no.

Comment: "But when i try to use it in any of the DownloadViewController extensions" <--- can you show how you did this?

Comment: @Sweeper updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you set you variable in Download view controller to = false 
It should be isFromChangeLanguague : Bool?

Comment: No i tried it. It will be set properly when i print the variable from `viewDidLoad` but from inside the delegate functions it will be nil